# Matrix differential equation. Solve Ax'=Bx+b

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have the matrix differential equation `Ax'=Bx+b`, where `A` and `B` are matrices of  `N*N`, and `b` is a vector.

I want to solve it with python. Hope someone could help me.

Cheers!

Comment: what attempts have you made?

Comment: Do you want a numeric or exact answer?

Comment: I have tried to solve it with odeint, but I dont know how to do it properly. The exact answer would be the best, but I think that is not possible to solve it analytical

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see the guide on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll find people to be a lot more willing to help you if you've posted code showing a strong attempt.

Comment: @Ricku could you a simple example of inputs and output desired?

Answer (score 1):

If your matrix `A` is regular, the function to pass to `odeint` is

```
def odefunc(x,t):
    return numpy.linalg.solve(A, B.dot(x)+c)
```

You can of course also compute the inverse of `A` and left-multiply the equation with it.

```
B = numpy.linalg.solve(A, B)
c = numpy.linalg.solve(A, c)
odefunc = lambda x,t: B.dot(x)+c
```